# Where should I place this library in my android app?

Tags: android, html, textview

I just downloaded this library ( http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html ) to display equations. Now I have my equation in an html document. So far so good. My question is:

1. Can I just load that html document in a textview in my android app?
2. If so, where do I have to place those the html document and the jquery library in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this tut might be useful

http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/included-demo-apps

and you may have a similar problem so consider the following

[Help using JQuery in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5422272/help-using-jquery-in-android-webview)

Answer (score 0):

You can display HTML content into a WebView control in your Android app.
You can place the html document into the app assets.

Comment: and what about the jquery libraries? do i have to place them anywhere?

Comment: Where are they referenced ? In your html document ? If so, you should place them where your html document can access it.